# Wait for event to be cleared in Python

Tags: python, events, python-multithreading

I searched all over the web, but I didn't found a clean solution for waiting an `Event` in `Python` to be cleared.

Is there an easy and clean solution available already (am I missing something?), or could I use as a workaround another `Event`-object that is being negated when the main `Event`-object is set or cleared?

Comment: There isn't such a way. Events are intended to be used for simple "wait for a thing to happen" scenarios.

Comment: I can't think of anything better than a class that wraps two event objects.